# why won't IE store my cookie?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, cookies

I'm developing a (J2EE) website, and the cookies it sends are being persisted on Chrome and Firefox, but not IE. I've even set IE up to 'allow all cookies', but the ones from my site are not being persisted. Google, Twitter etc, cookies do get persisted.

Here is my code to create and pass the cookie (HTTP):

```
Cookie rememberMeCookie = new Cookie("tms-remember-me", username);
rememberMeCookie.setPath("; HttpOnly");
rememberMeCookie.setMaxAge(365*24*60*60);
rememberMeCookie.setSecure(false);
rememberMeCookie.setVersion(1);
response.addCookie(rememberMeCookie);
response.setHeader("P3P", "CP=\"CURa ADMa DEVa CONo HISa OUR IND DSP ALL COR\"");
```

Using Fiddler for IE, I see that my login page is correctly sending a cookie:

```
Response sent 65 bytes of Cookie data:
    Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=1B7FCA42674BB275364A71F8BCEA4F4E; Path=/tms/; HttpOnly

Response sent 121 bytes of Cookie data:
    Set-Cookie: tms-remember-me=superuser; Version=1; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Fri, 16-Jun-2017 01:03:13 GMT; Path="; HttpOnly;"; Secure

P3P Header is present:
    CP="CURa ADMa DEVa CONo HISa OUR IND DSP ALL COR"
```

But IE still won't persist the cookie - when I visit my login page the HttpServletRequest getCookies() contains only the `JSESSIONID` cookie, not my `tms-remember-me` cookie.  But it IS present if I use Chrome or FF.  Any idea why not for IE?